# Loading PGadmin III GUI Linux

Tags: postgis, boundless-suite, linux, gui, pgadmin-3

Having tested out the functionality of OpenGeo Suite Community, I have installed the Linux version on my Centos 5 Server. However unlike in windows the dashboard is greyed out for Post GIS. I believe this is because the local web interface limits access due to security? where as in windows you can bypass this by loading the desktop client. I don't think you can load the local GUI without using a browser on Centos?

I read I need to run PGadmin separately, however I cannot find it in Linux when it should have installed along with the OpenGeo Suite Community?

In short how can I access the PGadmin interface? or re-install it? I found the Enterprise GUI installers do not work similarly to other posters on here.

Comment: Hi Tom. Welcome to GIS SE! What install method did you use btw? Also, is this a headless server?

Comment: Hi, I used the yum repository for CentOS 5, 32 bit http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/linux/centos/suite.html                             Eventually it will be a headless server, however for development purposes, I would like to use PGadmin rather than sql to access the PostGIS

Comment: usually you'd run pgadmin on your windows box pointing it at the linux box

Comment: Have you checked if pgadmin is at Applications > Programming? Alternatively, you could check if pgadmin is installed by running `rpm -qa | grep pgadmin` in your terminal.

Comment: It isn't in programming let me check with the terminal

Comment: It isn't showing it as installed, which is the issue. I installed the suite version that includes it. However it doesn't list it. I have tried installing the PostgreSQL from the yum repository and no luck. When I check is the postgresql has worked and try install it, it tells me it is already present. so why no pgadmin

Comment: Maybe you can try installing pgadmin itself? It should be a separate package. A `yum install pgadmin3` or  should do the trick (Assuming you have the right repositories)

Comment: It's saying missing dependency. I tried via wget and downloading the file direct the postgreSQL Repository from http://yum.pgrpms.org/repopackages.php#pg92 Centos 5, 32 bit, it has installed but I still cant find pgadmin

Comment: is it possible to open up a client screen for OpenGeo in Linux as you would with Windows. All the docs point to using the web browser, which I know from my testing with windows doesn't support postGIS you have to be in client mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: It wasn't clear about the dependency requirements for pgadmin when you install it. Found the files, (wxGTK-Base-2.8.12-1.elgi386.rpm)